# Recover/Carve FAT32 file system metadata (file names etc.) without partition table

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, file-recovery, fat32

I have a broken SD card, of which I've taken an image. The image is fairly complete, >99% according to `ddrescue`, and conventional data recovery tools seem to be able to find most files. However, I'd like to extract as much of the file system metadata (file names, directory structure) too.

`testdisk` did not manage to recover the relevant partition information. My assumption is that the SD card got formatted, only overwriting the partition table stuff while keeping the data intact.

So, how do I extract as much of the path names from this corrupt file system? I know that the partition I am interested was FAT32 formatted, and its rough size and location (thanks to entropy analysis).

Comment: Try [Remo Recover Windows](https://www.remosoftware.com/remo-recover-windows).

Comment: @harrymc Is this a "try this, good luck" or are you genuinely recommending it to solve my specific problem?

Comment: Strange question, but its screenshots seem like it conserves folder structure. And good luck, if you wish.

Comment: @harrymc Tried it out, but unfortunately it looks like it only wants to restore from phyisal disks. But I have a disk image. (And mounting the disk image is difficult given that it's corrupt)

Comment: well, which is it: '*broken*' whatever that means or *reformatted*? what can be recovered and if file system can de used for recovery depends on what's actually wrong. Edit question to make it more clear what we're dealing with.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I've already outlined in the question that >99% of the blocks could successfully be read, and that among those blocks who are missing/corrupted are any partition tables/headers. "broken" and "reformatted" are not mutually exclusive: the card is "broken" since some blocks couldn't be read, and it likely has been "reformatted" as in some information has been overwritten. However, the latter part is just an assumption I can't verify.

Comment: if reformatted, testdisk should have no trouble finding volume meta data as that was freshly written when reformatted. so gist of my question is more about what you base your analysis on. if reformatted you lose file allocation tables and root. entirely different recovery than recovery from volume with some bad blocks while file system is largely intact.

Comment: "Broken" is an unspecific term which does not disclose if the dammage is on a physical or logical level. I agree with Joe van Steen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The image is fairly complete, >99% according to ddrescue

Then analyse the image using a proper file system recovery tool, I use DMDE for cases like these.

> My assumption is that the SD card got formatted, only overwriting the
> partition table stuff while keeping the data intact.

Reformatting wipes file allocation tables + root folder. Again use a proper file recovery tool. DMDE for example will be able to show if file allocation tables are largely empty and if they are, the file system was indeed reformatted probably.

[image]

In case file system reformatted, assume:

- file/folder names in root are lost. Files from root need to be recovered using RAW recovery
- non contiguous files will be corrupt after recovery

Non contiguous or fragmented files may be recoverable but it depends on file type and if a specific tool was developed for it. For example tools exist that try reconstruct fragmented JPEG or MP4 files for example.

> overwriting the partition table

Does not influence recovery of files including original names, folder structure at all. IOW, 100% recovery possible.

Comment: Thank you this did work, although I did not manage to recover any data that was not already in my backups.

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption is that the SD card got formatted, only overwriting the partition table stuff while keeping the data intact.

Formatting is an operation that affects primarily a partition. The partition table comes into play when the file system format operation establishs a file system different from the preceding one. In this case the file system information in the partition table needs to be updated.
Otherwise there is no need to touch the partition table at all.

As the root directory is empty after a format operation on a FAT32 file system it has to be either overwritten (meaning deletion of metadata information for files and folders in the root directory) or an empty one written to a different location. In the later case a deletion is not necessary but the affected clusters of the old root directory will be released thus marked as free. FAT32 is not fixed in terms of root directory location as far as I remember.

Comment: "FAT32 is not fixed in terms of root directory location as far as I remember." - correct, but default appears cluster 2.

Comment: Thank you!

That means when formating a FAT32 file system at least cluster 2 and the following ones belonging to the root directory need to be overwritten.

Comment: Yes. + FAT zeroed + FSInfo sector needs updating. + as you say partition table needs editing if file system changes (exFAT to NTFS etc.).